# how to get selected attribute value in datalist using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datalist

```js
$("input[name=TypeList]").focusout(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="s" name = "TypeList" list = "TypeList" placeholder = "Select Type"/>
<datalist id = "TypeList">
   <option  data="1" data-value="1">Internet Explore1</option>
   <option data-value="4">Internet Explore4</option>
   <option data-value="3">Internet Explore3</option>
   <option data-value="2">Internet Explore2</option>
</datalist>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if there is any easier solution than this. Try below.

```js
$("input[name=TypeList]").focusout(function(){
     console.log($([].slice.call($(this)[0].list.children).filter((e) => {     
     
     return e.value === $(this).val();
     })).attr('data-value'));
});
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="s" name = "TypeList" list = "TypeList" placeholder = "Select Type"/>
<datalist id = "TypeList">
   <option  data="1" data-value="1">Internet Explore1</option>
   <option data-value="4">Internet Explore4</option>
   <option data-value="3">Internet Explore3</option>
   <option data-value="2">Internet Explore2</option>
</datalist>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [jQuery `:contains()` pseudo-class selector](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) to select based on content.

```js
$("input[name=TypeList]").focusout(function(){
    alert($(`#TypeList option:contains('${this.value}')`).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="s" name = "TypeList" list = "TypeList" placeholder = "Select Type"/>
<datalist id = "TypeList">
   <option  data="1" data-value="1">Internet Explore1</option>
   <option data-value="4">Internet Explore4</option>
   <option data-value="3">Internet Explore3</option>
   <option data-value="2">Internet Explore2</option>
</datalist>
</body>
```

For an exact match, you have to use the [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```js
$("input[name=TypeList]").focusout(function() {
  var val = this.value;
  alert($('#TypeList option').filter(function() {
    return val === this.value;
  }).data('value'));
});
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <input id="s" name="TypeList" list="TypeList" placeholder="Select Type" />
  <datalist id="TypeList">
   <option  data="1" data-value="1">Internet Explore1</option>
   <option data-value="4">Internet Explore4</option>
   <option data-value="3">Internet Explore3</option>
   <option data-value="2">Internet Explore2</option>
</datalist>
</body>
```

***FYI :*** For getting `data-*` value use jQuery [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data) method.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).val()` should do the job for you.. :)

```js
$("input[name=TypeList]").focusout(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input  id="s" name = "TypeList" list = "TypeList" placeholder = "Select Type"/>
<datalist id = "TypeList">
   <option  data="1" data-value="1">Internet Explore1</option>
   <option data-value="4">Internet Explore4</option>
   <option data-value="3">Internet Explore3</option>
   <option data-value="2">Internet Explore2</option>
</datalist>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this by reacting on the change event of the input value:

```
$(function(){
    $('#s').change(function(){
        console.log($("#TypeList option[value='" + $('#s').val() + "']").attr('id'));
    });
});
```